# Ho to get key.pem from a couple of .cert files

Tags: openssl, pem

I have two files `bx.crt` and `CA.crt`. How do I get a key.pem from them? Both files are binary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If those are certificate files, then you can't.  Certificate files don't contain a private key, only the public key.  You will need to "find" the private key file that generated the certificate request.